# IIS not secured after adding hid aspx ext to URL rewite

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-8

I have a windows server 2016 Standard.
I have SSL installed and working fine. I also add the following to URL rewrite to redirect http to https:

```
 <rules>
            <rule name="ssl redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

Now I added a Rule to hide my extension:

```
<rule name="hide .aspx ext" enabled="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
            </rule>
```

However, now, I don't get the secure symbol (the lock icon) any more and saying the site is not secure. what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL rewrite shouldn't report this error when you just rewrite for friendly URL.Did you receive this error in Edge or chrome?

1.I notice that you are using **MatchAny** for your rule.Based on my understanding you should use **MatchAll** instead.

```
     <rule name="hide .aspx ext" enabled="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

2.What error message did you receive when chrome report site is not secure? Did you 
 receive something likeNET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID ? Please open chrome  F12 developer tool->Seucrity. You should be find the root cause. Please ensure your are using a valid certificate with valid domain and SAN.

3.Please ensure the http binding and https binding are hosted in differernt site. To 
enable SSL, you need to enable Require SSL. Then SSL handshake will corrupt http request from same site. So you need another site to handle http request and do the redirection.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jokies Ding,  Thanks for helpful reply. That did it. I changed "MatchAny"  to "MatchAll" and it is working fine